# How can I change the default `init.el` file Emacs automatically searches for?

Tags: init-file

I am new to emacs. Following the instruction online, the default customization file is in my home directory and is under the name `.emacs`. I want to follow the tutorial I am currently going over and want to save everything in a folder and upload it to my GitHub repo for future reference. However, the folder I am currently working in is the `\emacs.d` folder and I did have another copy of `init.el` file under that folder. I am wondering if it's possible to force emacs to follow the customization under that `init.el` file instead of loading `.emacs` in my home directory?

Comment: See the Emacs manual, node [Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), for places you can put your init file and what you can call it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a priority order for possible init file names, and Emacs will use the first one that it finds.

If you don't want it to use `~/.emacs` then you'll have to make sure that file does not exist so that it will continue looking for other possibilities.

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Find Init`